# Hairline crack in concrete driveway

Tags: concrete, driveway, crack

Should I do anything about this? The crack is about 1/16 inch and four or five feet long and first appeared mid-winter. The driveway was poured just over a year before the crack appeared.

I've heard there is a product that is water like and seeps into the crack to prevent water getting in and widening the crack once winter sets in but I haven't gone to the hardware store to look for it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of concrete: Concrete that that **is cracked** and concrete that **will crack**.

There are several products that work well to seal cracks. Oover the years I have found the types that stay flexible to be the best —especially if in a region that has low winter temps below 25F.  Below that temperature, I find water will cause more damage if not sealed.